# How to use generators with exprerss.js streams?

Tags: javascript, express, stream, generator

This is what i am using at the moment:

```js
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {

  res.set('Content-type', 'text/plain');
  res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');

  const stream = new Stream.Readable({ read() { } });
  stream.pipe(res);

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let result = JSON.stringify({ bar: i});
    res.cork();
    stream.push(`${result}\n`);
    freeze(50);
    process.nextTick(() => res.uncork());
  }

  res.end();

})
```

Is it possible that the client gets the next bar object using a generator, sort of the client controls when then next bar object will be streamed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement? Perhaps there are other solutions more suitable (like `WebSocket`)?

Comment: The client needs some time to process the data it receives from every chunk, that is why i freeze on the server side for 50 milliseconds. So i want the client to say give me the next chunk when the previous chunk data finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) for the suggestion. I used socket.io to implement a simple example. The client controls the pace of the stream.

**Server side**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

function* numsGenerator() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

io.of("/stream").on("connection", (socket) => {
  const gen = numsGenerator();
  socket.on('stream:get', () => {
    socket.emit('stream:result', gen.next());
  });

});

const port = 4000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('\nReady for requests on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

**Client side**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="module">
    import { io } from "https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.1/socket.io.esm.min.js";

    const socket = io("ws://localhost:4000/stream");

    socket.emit('stream:get');

    socket.on("stream:result", (result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if (result.done) return;
      socket.emit('stream:get');
    });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```